# Random permutations constructed via randomly chosen transpositions

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, permutations, random-permutations

Given positive integers $k$ and $n$, we define the probability distribution $p_{n,k}$ on $S_n$ as:

$$
p_{n,k}(\sigma):=\frac{\#\{(\tau_1,\dots,\tau_s)\mid \sigma=\tau_1\dots\tau_s, \text{ each }\tau_i\in S_n \text{ is a transposition and } s \in \{0,\dots,k\}\}}{\sum_{s=0}^k\binom{n}{2}^s}\quad (\sigma\in S_n).
$$
This assigns the same mass to elements of each conjugacy class, but is in general different from the uniform distribution on $S_n$ - which we denote by $u_n$. For instance, its support is not the whole $S_n$ if $k<n-1$.

I am interested to see what can be said about the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures) (denoted by $\delta$) between $p_{n,k}$ and $u_n$, at least asymptotically. More precisely:

- Is there any upper bound for $\delta(p_{n,k},u_n)$ in terms of $k$ and $n$? With $n$ fixed, for what value of $k$ (if any) this distance is minmized? What is the asymptotic behavior if $k$ is a function of $n$ e.g. $k=n-1$?

Comment: Your measure and the measure where $s=k$ are very close. The latter case corresponds to convolving the uniform probability measure on transpositions $k$ times, which on the Fourier side (whatever that means :) ) corresponds to multiplication $k$ times. Using the representation theory of $S_n$, this was studied in an important paper of Diaconis-Shahshahani from 1981, "Generating a random permutation with random transpositions", where it was shown that the total variation distance decays exponentially in $(k-(\log n)/2)/n$, and that this is optimal in a precise sense.

Comment: Small correction: since a product of $k$ transpositions has fixed parity, Diaconis and Shahshahani actually convolved a measure which is supported on transpositions *and* the identity.